# Help with separating functions over arbitrary separation of variables proof?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Amateur mathematician here,

Given three arbitrary functions f(x), g(x), and h(x), is it possible to find three functions F(x,y), G(x), and H(x) such that f(x) = F(g(x),h(x)) = G(g(x))H(h(x))? If so, is it proven already? If not, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: Are you asking if, given three arbitrary functions f(x), g(x), and h(x), you can construct three new functions l(x,y), G(x), and H(x) s.t. f(x)=l(g(x),h(x) and f(x)=G(g(x))H(h(x))? Or are you asking given f(x), l(x,y), G(x), and H(x), if you can find g(x) and h(x) such that those two equalities hold?

Comment: I'm asking the first.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The way you show that is with a counterexample.

f(x)=x, g(x)=2, h(x)=3. It is impossible to find any functions that can recreate f(x) from a domain of only 1 point.